# Why is substrate written like this?

Tags: design

I am curious about the way substrate is written. Let's take for example the assets pallet. Most of the functions in the lib.rs file don't reveal too much detail, but enough to understand what each function does. Most of them call the "do" methods in the function.rs file where most of the logic is placed, hence some of them are pretty long and reveal a lot of detail. I am interested in why don't some of these functions get separated into multiple smaller functions. I believe that it would be much easier to follow and read the code that way. This is just my opinion, but there might be a good reason for writing code like this.

Comment: Substrate SE was created partially to allow wider scoped questions where the answers would still benefit some other people in the Polkadot/Kusama/Substrate ecosystem. Could you please rephrase your question in a way that it might be answered to benefit others as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRs welcome. There's a lot going on in substrate and as Ethereum's successor(s) it's designed to be a lot more generic than Ethereum was (as it will be used in many more different contexts). Sometimes if you split a function too fine  it can be hard to see what's going on. There's a balance, and everyone's view of what 'right' looks like is different. With as big a codebase as substrate's, there is always room for improvement - if you can refactor any small part of the code to be more readable then happy to review the PR.

Answer (score 0):

The `do_*` functions are generally re-used in some pallets from inside the extrinsics. So it is sharable logic.